Source tab in components Experience space
The source tab near General tab like classic UI is missing for components in experience space. Is there a way to enable it in experience space?

No, it is currently not possible to see Component source (XML) in Experience Space.
As a matter of fact, the Core Service REST public API (on which Experience Space frontend is built) currently does not expose custom content/metadata as XML at all; Core Service REST uses a JSON fields abstraction.
We are considering providing access to "raw" XML through Core Service REST in a future release, but would be good to know your use case for a Source tab in Experience Space.

Thanks for the reply. We have customization to add hyperlinks with different attributes, html tags, placeholders for the content and validating in the source tab. We did not enable the source for each field in RTF so expecting a common source tab as like classic UI.

So, it is specifically about being able to see/edit XHTML source of Rich Text Fields? Please consider submitting an idea on https://community.rws.com/ideas/tridion-ideas/i/tridion-sites-ideas
